# ExtJS 2.x Grid Cell Validation for Duplicate Data

Tags: extjs, extjs2

I have ExtJS Grid In which I have Columns called "Mobile Number".
I have made simple thing here When I edit more than 2 rows and If I Modify the Column "Mobile Number" It will be checked whether is it Exist in Grid or Not.

If Duplicate Number found, I will give Message that the Input Mobile Number is already Exist and 
reloading the whole grid so all edited data will be gone.

But, I want the non-duplicate data back was edited.

So, How can I keep my non-duplicate data as it is after reload the whole Grid.

I just want to remove duplicate row where found duplication and other edited rows keep as it is.

> Can I use this RowEditor plugin for ExtJS 2.x compatible.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/row-editor.html

My E-mail: ashwin.parmar2020@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `validator` for the mobile number field that detects duplicates and refuse the duplicate number. So you don't have to reload the grid.

If you want to reload the grid anyways, you could get the `dirty` rows before doing so and store/reapply them afterwards.

To get the dirty records you can use the `getModifiedRecords()` function of the grids store. Use the `commitChanges`function of the store to apply them after validation/processing.

Comment: Can you give example how to get dirty rows and reapply after reload my grid so non-duplicate rows keep as it is in grid after reload untill I commit the grid data.

Comment: I edited my answer. I would suggest you store the dirty records before the reload or find a way where no reload is needed.

Answer (score 1):

To find duplicate data use `afteredit` event of  `Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel` on that event you will get current record, so just  display message and add empty value in that field